# 雙注　Double zhuyin?

Tags: input-methods, zhuyin-fuhao

*Feel free to skip to "Questions" below*

**Background:**

I'm a cangjie typist and only really use phonetic methods when looking up new words I don't know the shape of.

But I'm interested in double zhuyin schemas or possibly programming my own to speed up the search process.

**Reasons:**

1. I feel zhuyin more accurately represents Mandarin phonetics.
2. I'm more comfortable with the zhuyin layout.
3. Using ziranma shuangpin is a little strange to me because I'm so familiar with the zhuyin layout and zhuyin phonetics.
4. I like to have the option of tone input, which shuangpin lacks, to be more accurate.
5. I'd like to speed up the search process a bit and lessen the required keystrokes.

This is just an example I made up:
[image: This is just an example I made up]

incorporating the doubled-finals from:
[image]

I found this extant double zhuyin schema, but it uses a different layout and only 26 keys. (Source: https://github.com/imper0502/rime-double-bopomo )
[image]

Zhuyin is naturally designed to use the left hand, then the right hand, and then tone markings. But I suppose you could do something similar to rime's zhuyin in making tones optional. This change would change the maximum number of keystrokes to 2 or 3 (with tones) from 4. So, perhaps this is why I've had trouble finding a double zhuyin schema?

For those unfamiliar with the standard zhuyin layout, here's an image with pinyin annotation:
[image: zhuyin-layout]

**Questions:**

1. Does anyone else have interest in such double zhuyin schemas?
2. Does anyone know of an existing double zhuyin schema using the standard zhuyin layout?
3. Has anyone here ever made a custom layout with shuangpin?
4. Does anyone know of a shuangpin IME that has optional tones?

If no one else has interest, I will probably just use the standard rime zhuyin when I need to phonetically lookup some new words, even though double zhuyin with optional tones would probably be faster.

Comment: I'm a native zhuyin user in Taiwan. No one use and never seen this kind of keyboard layout.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, you are correct. It's just an idea to possibly create a new input method. I don't know if anyone would want to use it. 感謝你的回復。對啊. 我考慮製作一個新輸入法為注音類似於雙拼輸入法但是使用標準的注音鍵盤佈局。 使用者可以使用或沒使用聲調. 我不知道如果注音使用者想使用這樣的注音輸入法。我是一個倉頡打字員, 但是我使用注音當我不知道字形。

Comment: 比方說"倉頡"的注音碼是[j; ru,6]但是我雙注碼是[j; rw]或者[j; rw6]跟聲調.